# Citrix server running 3rd party app experiencing SQL timeouts

Tags: sql-server, citrix

We are running an app that was not developed in house on several Citrix servers.  The users of this application are experiencing intermittent SQL timeouts. The error message:

"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

We're not seeing any errors on our SQL server, and we don't have the option to modify the code to resolve the problem.  Is there a way to modify SQL connection properties for all connections made from the Citrix server?

Thanks,

Graham

Comment: Is the connection to the SQL server done through an ODBC DSN or using the SQL native client directly in the application?

Comment: are you running out of network resources? how many users..send more logs files and debug

Comment: I am facing the same error . I tried Database index rebuild as well . It did not help

Answer (score 0):

Have a check on SQL Server Maintenance Plan, it sounds like some database index needs rebuild. In the worst case some database index may be missing at all, so application databases need some performance tuning.